# Inserting golang slice directly into postgres array

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a problem with inserting slice into postgres array directly and can't find a simple solution.

Given:

```
favorites := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
// need to 
_, err = db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE users SET favorites = '{%v}';", favorites))
```

Because of input is '{[1,2,3,4,5]}' instead of '{1,2,3,4,5}' I have an error.
I am using default SQL package and "github.com/lib/pq" postgres driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pq.Array(favorites) to insert it correctly. As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/array.go)

It would be like:

```
favorites := []int{1,2,3,4,5}

query:= "UPDATE users SET favorites = $1;"

_, err = db.Exec(query, pq.Array(favorites))
```

Comment: Maybe I have this behaviour because of the type of the slice (it is initially pq.Int64Array)?

Comment: In that case your slice should be []int64{1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: @ArthurBerg `pq.Array` used properly, i.e. passed directly to `db.Exec` and with **`$1`** instead of `fmt` and `{%v}` does **not** produce `{[1,2,3,4,5]}`. First you may want to read up on SQL injections, then you should stop using `fmt` and plain string interpolation for query construction, and finally try to follow the suggestions in an answer thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

using pq.array to the respective golang slice will help you to insert the array.

```
q = q.Values(result.Id, result.Text, result.CreatedAt, pq.Array(result.EditHistoryTweetIds))
```

here EditHistoryTweetIds will be golang slice.